Magento 2: where to check layout block cache in core files?
I would like to know core file where it checks layout block cache or not and add block in layout cache?
I found out following classes but I dont know from which file it checks the conditions for every block and add block in layout cache?
Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Layout 

    Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder

Please help

Hello @Niraj, Please check Magento\Framework\View\Layout
